# How to tag properly

Tags: discussion, tags

Always when I ask a question or if I feel I should retag an other users question I ask myself

> What are the proper tags for that?

Take a SQL question for instance asking for help with a select query.

I could just tag [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) 
or with proper DB engine tag [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) 
or both and even more DB engines [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) [sql-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2)
and besides that I could add other tags making it [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) [sql-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2) [query](/questions/tagged/query) [select](/questions/tagged/select)

How can I decide what is proper?
Does it hurt to add as much fitting tags as possible?

Comment: Shouldn't it be [sql] [sql-server] [sql-server-2008-r2] ? [query] and [select] are just pure crap IMHO.

Comment: Why would you ask the OP? @benisuǝqbackwards

Comment: I agree with [select] and [query] being not so helpful, but would really like to know what the community thinks about that. But in general and not just for my example.

Comment: The OP is one of the top answers in SQL @11684 and I run into him regularly... I actually disagree with his tagging style in these examples, (not including [sql-server]), which comes as a bit of a surprise so I'm querying it.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I didn't want to imply that I tag as in my example. These are just possiblities to tag. And there are way more. It is just an example of what I say in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself: does the tag categorize the question effectively?

You might as well tag [sql](/questions/tagged/sql).  That's the language being used, and tagging the question with the language being used is pretty much standard practice on Stack Overflow.

[sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) can be useful, since some SQL Server features are version-specific.

[sql-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2) is unlikely to be useful, unless you're asking specifically about a feature that was added in that version.

The remaining tags are not exactly useless, but they're not all that useful either, given that the question is almost certainly going to be about a SQL query anyway, and SELECT queries are arguably the most common type of SQL query.

Comment: I came up with my question because I saw another top answerer in the SQL section retagging a question he answered with [query] and [select]. I thought: Is this to get badges for that tags or has it reason to add so much tags.

Comment: I just don't see how a retag like that adds much value.  It's not exactly incorrect, but meh.