# Burninate mysql-error-1064

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[This is discussed a little bit here as well.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176318/what-is-considered-incorrect-tagging)

The tag [mysql-error-1064](/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1064) is on almost 1000 questions at this point.  It is also useless.

The error code in question is about the most generic error you can get - "There is an error in your syntax"!

If you need help, searching using this tag is useless because the tag is so generic - there's pretty much no way that your issue will be the same as someone else's issue based solely on this error code.

Additionally, a large number of these questions are likely **Too Localized** since they boil down to syntax errors.

**I request that this tag be burninated as useless.**

Comment: **Public Service Announcement:**  There are only two ways to remove a tag without involving a Stack Exchange Developer: synonymizing the tag with another tag, or removing each tag instance individually.  Developers are only involved when it's an emergency.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well that changes things somewhat.

Comment: To add to Robert's PSA, since many of these questions should probably be closed, it's probably worth it to do this tag removal manually.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I like that idea!

Comment: Burninating a tag should also be done only if the tag keeps to be used, and there is no way to remove it because there is a new question using it for every question from which the tag is removed. If removing the tag is not successfull, and there is no tags for which it can be made a synonym, then burninating could be requested.

Comment: I suspect the total number of down-votes on this request to be either zero or one - but no more than one.

Comment: Every day there are several new questions posted about this mysql error code, even though hundreds of answers already say "This is a syntax error, check your syntax!". So many people never bother reading the MySQL manual or checking their queries.

Comment: @Jocelyn That doesn't mean it's an informative tag, though.  I'm not sure if you are trying to condone keeping it or not, but that tag adds essentially 0 information to the question.  It may as well be "error".

Comment: @JNK I completely agree with your post here and all explanations given.

Comment: Maybe we should *keep* the tag, as it's a honeypot for questions that, being syntax errors, are likely to be too localized and thus close-bait.

Comment: @Charles I'm working on getting them all closed per bill's suggestion

Comment: Can I get paid in rep to burniate this tag? I'm thinking 200/rep/hour is a fair market rate.

Comment: I've got my close votes review queue filter set to 'burninate'.

Comment: Also discussed here [Do we really need a tag for every error code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66352/145673)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Isn't there a way for 10K users or moderators to close-vote the questions in this list more efficiently? (I don't exactly know the tools 10K users or moderators have access to)

Comment: @Jocelyn If you just close vote them without removing the tag, I'll see them when I filter on that tag. That way we can close/delete the ones that can't be salvaged through editing a little bit faster.

Comment: mysql and sql Doubts and Solutions visit http://www.allinonescript.com/search/label/MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with some data-queries the low hanging fruits can be picked more easily for deletion. Not that this query is perfect, but it can be a start:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/112147

Comment: I prefer to use [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=[mysql-error-1064]%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano) and go to the last pages to get the questions with the lowest scores.