# What is the purpose of tag "blank"? burninate?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Just found one question on SO with the tag [blank](/questions/tagged/blank). Got intrigued and went after explanation. Found empty wiki but used in 458 questions. **Edit**: <del>241</del> <s>179</s> <s>150</s> <s>61</s> <s>50</s> now.

## 0 to go!

Some tagged it because of [*target="_blank"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541255/open-in-new-tab-target-blank-html), others relating to [*blank page*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431259/blank-page-when-use-jquery), others [*I'm getting a blank data report in vb6*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218089/im-getting-a-blank-data-report-in-vb6), etc

I feel this is a confusing and not helpful tag. Can someone clarify it so we can add a wiki to it, or should this tag be burninated?

Comment: It’s useless, but will probably take some care; not too many to retag manually. I’m working on it too :D

Comment: @minitech, I saw you were out there :) had to update post from 483 to 481... hmmm now in 473. You are fast...

Comment: a `target-blank` tag? what next, `mysqli-query-not-working-as-it-should` tag? :P

Comment: @James close: [tag:mysql-error-1064]

Comment: @ColeJohnson It has 58 questions *right now*.

Comment: @michael958 I thought it was burninated a few days ago?

Comment: @ColeJohnson still in the works I guess http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177630/burninate-mysql-error-1064

Comment: Still 458 to un-tag. I go and work on some of them...

Comment: I was trying to see why my PHP wasn't writing anything to the browser and I drew a blank ... `</groan>`

Comment: But if the tags are bad, aren't the questions bad as well, and better left alone rather than being bumped due to an edit? What harm is done leaving such tags in place (and then, indeed, allow < 1.5k rep question askers to abuse them again)?

Comment: @Arjan Not all of the questions are bad.

Comment: Now in my list.  The tag shall be made to suffer.

Comment: Don't just untag all of them. In many scenario's it will be better to retag with a more meaningful tag.

Comment: @Arjan Problems with questions should be fixed. I remember a meta discussion about fixing minor spelling errors on very old posts - the conclusion was that we should do it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, great job also!

Comment: @Sergio: glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tag was unclear/useless and all 481 questions have now been un-tagged

Comment: So the blank tag is now *blank*.