# How do I learn how to review on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, low-quality-posts

On gaining extra review privileges I wanted to know the rules for reviewing. There is no link from the review privilege descriptions. After some searching I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing). It would be good if the privilege descriptions had links to that question or a better one.

As I review suggested edits I see several trivial changes (eg spelling where the meaning is obvious, white space, adding or altering quote marks, changing a URL in the text to Hyperlink) and I wonder whether I should approve them or not.

Having chosen a response then how do I find out how my response affected the outcome of a review? How do I learn whether my response was correct or at least matched the majority of other responses?

Comment: You can see the outcome of your review decisions here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history

Answer (score 1):

According to me these edits should be approved even if some reviewers may think them as *too minor*.

1. Formatting in code or logcat. (removing extra white space)

   This helps other users read question properly. I seriously get annoyed when I see a question which contains unformatted logcat or code.
2. Spelling mistakes and grammatical errors.

   Mainly, when the user might have wrote `Therad` instead of `Thread` or there is a grammatical error, and suggested edit fixes *all such errors in question*, I would approve that.

Comment: _"and suggested edit fixes all such errors in question"_ that is the key bit for me, so many editors see 1 or 2 fixes and approve. IMO if you're going to suggest an edit the **vast** majority of mistakes should be fixed. It shouldn't take 4 edits to get a post looking right.

Comment: @OGHaza For example, a user edits a post that has 5-6 same type of grammatical error/ spelling mistakes and the editor just corrects 1-2 problems and submits it. If s/he fixes the problems, then s/he should fix all 5-6 problems. that's what I meant.

Comment: I'd also add a bullet for correct tagging - adding a missing tag that's crucial for exposure (like a language tag) is IMHO justified (assuming it doesn't leave other errors ignored), but adding a minor tag (like `for-loop`, see - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214565/tags-of-mundanity-that-are-gratuitously-applied-to-posts/214568#214568) is pretty useless, especially when done as part of robo-editing

Comment: @Leeor I agree with you. Some new users might suggest a minor edit like just one typo fix (ignoring other errors) just for 2 points. That is the reason I said, 'fixes all such errors'.

Answer (score 1):

My biggest tip would be: **If you are unsure then hit Skip**.

Another tip I'd give is if you come across a suggested edit review that you're not sure whether to approve or reject, open up that same URL in a new tab, skip the review and continue with your reviewing.

After 60 seconds or so that review will have been completed by other people so you can switch back to that tab, refresh, and you'll be able to see what action the other reviewers chose to take along with the reasons any of them chose to reject it for.

Be warned though that there are **many** poor reviewers out there and there is certainly a tendency for people to approve edits - If a suggested edit was rejected by 2 people and approved by 3 it's very likely that the suggested edit was of a very low quality.

You can do the same for edits you do approve/reject - do a few reviews then hit back on the browser and you can see what the other reviewer's chose to do and what the final decision was. I do this all the time to ensure that actual bad edits get rejected - if they don't then I can go to the post myself and roll back/fix the post myself.

Comment: +1 for suggesting skip if unsure. That at least stops us from taking a wrong decision.