# Where do we draw the line on esoteric tag additions?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

A user has suggested many edits adding tags to questions like

- [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement) to a question involving an if statement
- [nested](/questions/tagged/nested) to a question titled "c#: Add element to second nesting in xml"
- [cursor-position](/questions/tagged/cursor-position) to a question titled "How to get exact cursor position in RichTextbox to display Popup "

these seem worthless to me. However, he claims otherwise (we are having a polite discussion about it, everybody be nice to him even if you agree with me!):

> Hmm I see what your after and from your POV I do agree. But there are people like myself searching for these tag belive it or not. I use them to mostly to illustrate common problems programmers run into. Otherwise they wouldn't be tags created by the SO community. I read the article you supplied to me good read.. but I think you focus to much on the value adding from YOUR pov. I always read the question and study the problem, and if theres a problem with a nested or and if-statement why not tag it. I mean when are those questions ever going to be tagged otherwise with those tags??

And indeed, [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement) [has been deemed not completely invalid by the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96219) for some reason. Still, I'd make the argument that none of these tags add any value to the question or its searchability.

Does a general guideline exist how to deal with this? How do we account for the fact that *we* may not be able to see the value in a borderline esoteric tag, but others do? How do we still have clear rules for this kind of situation?

Bonus question: what do we *call* tagging that simply describes what happens to be the question's subject matter, without really adding any relevance? It's not Meta tags, but it's something like them.

Comment: Tags are not a user's personal filing cabinet.  If a user is merely tagging so that they can find the questions again in a search, that's not sufficient reason to retag.

Comment: @Robert well, his argument is that *users like him* would search for those keywords. I can't see any real-world situation where that is true; when would you ever reasonably search for something like `if-statement`? But I'm open to the idea that maybe others can... and I'm hard pressed to find a previous Meta thread that defines an authoritative rule.

Comment: The tags you illustrated are well-used.  Granted, they don't seem to be all that useful for categorization, but some of us have ... more "specific" sensibilities than others.  Tag philosophy runs the gamut from typing a sentence into the tag dialog to "each and every tag has one, and only one, very specific meaning."  Neither extreme is ideal.

Comment: What would be the results of allowing _any_ kind of tag, no matter how little use?

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's the status quo now, provided the tag isn't completely wretched (we don't allow meta tags, or tags that fail at any sort of useful categorization).

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks. I'll try to apply that philosophy when reviewing unless this discussion brings up something else. Of course, the "you've added a tag but the question is still a mess" rule still applies.

Comment: Where's the post resoluting that meta-tags shall be verbotten?

Comment: @JanDvorak: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: I don't use tag like this, but we encourage users to search first, so tags for specific aspects of languages seems "searchable" in some context.  For example, if I don't know the right terms to use in a search, but I know I am having a problem with an `if-statement` in `c#`, it might help filter the list of questions down.  The problem because if the tag is used on questions that have an if-statement, rather than questions about an if-statement.

Comment: *"when would you ever reasonably search for something like if-statement?"* ... you wouldn't.

Comment: @bart: Except maybe for [tag:language-lawyer] questions (one of the very few meta tags that is permitted).

Comment: But then you would simply include it in your search terms @RobertHarvey. Still wouldn't need a tag for that, would you?

Comment: @Pëkka, there is [only one possible correct answer to this question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lE3IeNUzIo#t=34).

Comment: @Charles loool, I agree