# Reviewing suggested edits which add one or two not so important tags

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

During reviewing some of the suggested edits, I encountered with lots of questions which were edited to add just one tag or sometimes two.

I approved/rejected the edits on the basis of the severity of the tags added. But then I came to know that this type of editing was done by
 the same user.

- Some of the questions about this type of editing are

[ASP.NET 2.0 with conditional radio button in a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364570/1626878)

[Can I go from managed thread ID to ProcessThreadID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7262004/1626878)

[how allow DataGridView allow paging In C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7266696/1626878)

[Getting filenames from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7269484/1626878)

I found that almost all of the edits were approved. You can have a look at the [editor's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040039/sumon-banerjee?tab=reputation) who have generated lot of reputation with such edits. I just have the doubt that if it is okay to approve this type of 
editing. I have also asked for moderator attention for this.

Comment: Hmm.  I was about to link to [a recent similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220847/mass-tagging-of-laravel-questions-with-web-frameworks-how-to-react/220877#220877), but it's been deleted.  10k link there.  See also related: [Suggested edit system is causing grief, needs to be rethought](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220849/135887)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I review suggested edits which add just tags.

1. If the tag(s) is/are irrelevant to the post **reject it**.
2. If the tag(s) is/are relevant to the post:

   - If the post doesn't require further edits **approve it**.
   - If the post requires further edits:
   - If the required further edits are minor (e.g. didn't remove "Thanks in advance", minor speling mistakes etc) **improve it** and remove it.
   - If the required further edits are not minor (e.g. Didn't format the code or didn't correct speling/grammer mistakes on high amount of words) **improve it** and uncheck "*Suggested edit was helpful*" (this is up to you).

I do not mind if the same user suggests such edits repeatedly. But if he suggests incorrect edits (which requires further edits) repeatedly, I ping him and ask him to edit the body too when necessary.

Comment: What if the user adds a tag for just a single element of the code?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj: Do you mean edit and improve the body but not improve  everything?

Comment: No, for instance there was a question with some android code. In that code, OP had used gridviews, linearlayout, relative layout and many other elements. Then the editor edited the post adding gridview tag only.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj - (IMHO) I will approve it by keeping in mind that he may not know about the other tag(e.g. linearlayout) because suggesting multiple tag edits doesn't take too much time as compared to editing the body.