# How to prevent a new user suggesting bad edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

The new user named [shumanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3317705/shumanth)  is suggesting wrong edits (deleting the entire part of the answer) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21750595/3030434)  particular answer and in comments he is adding suggested by moderator.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3317705/shumanth?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) is the history of his suggestion

I have rejected it and fellow Users too have rejected his edit but even after that he is suggesting the same edit is there anyway to prevent him from suggesting edit..!!

Comment: Keep rejecting him. He will be auto banned from editing after a certain number of bad edits.

Comment: my bad 20 suggested edits for a day got over..!! :(

Comment: Looking at the history, most reviewers are quite level-headed and reject his edit, so don't worry about it.

Comment: is there any way to block these kind of users or where we can complain  about them??

Comment: [*Most* reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4077008). We need to shame hd1. Shaaame!

Comment: I guess he lost his eyesight..!! :P

Comment: By posting here, you already put up a complaint about him. I don't think you need to do anything further, since the system is working (most people are doing their job and rejects his edits), he will get banned from editing if he continues.

Comment: This one got one approval: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4077008 And of course, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220849/suggested-edit-system-is-causing-grief-needs-to-be-rethought

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - Only one reviewer approved it. Overall it was rejected.

Comment: @hims056 For such an edit, one is way too many.

Comment: and the one which is not acceptable is, the user who approved it has around 9k reputaion...!! :(

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about it. If his suggestions are rejected he will soon [be banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/187824) from suggesting edits at least for a week. Also, his every troll edits are rejected quickly. For this particular user he has 4 rejected edits. As per the formula `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5` he needs one more rejected edit to get ban.

Also, you don't need to complain about every troll editor, since they are banned automatically.

Comment: Yes, this guy's edits are (almost always) rejected (should be always!).  But too often, very bad edits get through.  Acceptance of edits is the norm, no thought necessary.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - Yeah, that is [the most frustrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561/187824) thing about reviewing suggested edits.