# Is it intentional that suggested edits are resolved so quickly?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, quality

Having just recently reached 2K rep and edit review capabilities I've noticed that suggested edits are typically approved/rejected in less than 10 seconds. If you take your time to read the suggested edit, you will almost certainly have it approved or rejected out from under you.

Is this intentional?

It seems to be impacting the quality of the review process.

If this is not intentional, I'd like to request a fix:

1. Parcel the suggested edits out to fewer reviewers, or
2. Lock the ability to approve/reject to the first reviewer for a short time (~ a minute?) to give enough time to carefully review the suggested edit

Comment: The problem is real.  Not so sure that either suggestion helps though.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220849/suggested-edit-system-is-causing-grief-needs-to-be-rethought/221429

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many that it's hard to choose one, so I'm going to use a nominal previous question as the dupe.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks like the answers to that question are from 2012, but still don't solve the problem in a good way.

Comment: Robo-reviewers notwithstanding, consider the number of people who have this privilege, and that it gets promoted in the navigation bar, and it's not really too surprising.